# ArrayList into ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I'm trying to put an arraylist method into an arrayadapter but i am unable to do so.
I am getting `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new Runnable(){}, int, ArrayList<RetrieveInternet>) is undefined`

ArrayAdapter

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getPackages());
```

Arraylist method:

```
private ArrayList<RetrieveInternet> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<RetrieveInternet> apps = getPermissions(true); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i);
        Log.e("TAG", apps.get(i).toString());
    }
    return apps;
}
```

Comment: The method parameter <RetrieveInternet> does not match the declared parameter <string>.  These must match.

Answer (score 2):

First parameter of `ArrayAdapter` constructor should be `Context` not `Runnable`. You are probably setting your adapter from within some `Runnable` so you cannot use `this` reference because it pointing at that `Runnable` instance. You should change this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getPackages());
```

into this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getPackages());
```

The main difference is first parameter - `YourActivity.this` which is reference to your activity in which you are setting your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are creating your adapter in a `Runnable` (in `run()` method), that's why `this` refers to the `Runnable`, not to a `Context`. Try to use `YourActivity.this` instead of `this`.