# printing an string array to listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

```
package com.fyp.khursani;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import test.fyp.khursani.library.JSONParser;

import com.fyp.khursani.activity.SingleListItem;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewDishes extends ListFragment {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static String url_menu = "http://192.168.56.1/khursaani/get_menu_details.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "menuItemName";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "menuItemPrice";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "menuItemDescription";
    private static final String TAG_UNIT = "menuItemUnit";
    private static final String TAG_IMG = "menuItemImage";
    private static final String TAG_MENU = "menu";

    //progress dialogue

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONArray events = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, container, false);

        // storing string resources into Array
        //            String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        //        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, adobe_products));
        new asyncmenu().execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    class asyncmenu extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameters2send = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_menu, "POST", postparameters2send);

            Log.d("response from php", json.toString());

            int status = 0;
            try {

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                JSONArray menu = null;
                menu = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MENU);
                String[] menuarray = new String[100];

                for (int i = 0; i < menu.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = menu.getJSONObject(i);
                    menuarray[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    Log.d("menu", menuarray[i]);
                }

                return menuarray;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String[] menuarray = new String[10];
            return menuarray;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            Log.d("onPostExecute", result[0]);

            ViewDishes.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, result));

        }
    }

}
```

In this file above , there was previously an array `R.array.adobe_products` which looked like this :

`String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);`

xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="adobe_products">
    <item>Tandoori Chicken</item>
    <item>Chicken Tikka</item>
    <item>Sheikh Kebab</item>
    <item>Tandoori Prawn</item>
    <item>Chicken Curry</item>
    <item>Chicken Do Pizza</item>
    <item>Nepal Ice</item>
    <item>Corona Beer</item>
    <item>Coca Cola</item>
    <item>Ginger Ale</item>
    <item>Vanilla Ice Cream</item>
    <item>Mango Melba</item>
    <item>Masala Chai</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

This was output to listfragment like this:

```
 this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

I now have an array of strings named result (in function `onPostExecute`) that is received after parsing a json file from a remote server, which is a plain array (as opposed to adobe_products, which is a fancy xml).

The array adobe_products is displayed as is expected. To display the new array (`result`), i've tried passing the new array in place of `adobe_products like so:

```
ViewDishes.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, result));
```

which doesn't seem to work[crashes].

LogCat output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
```

How can I display the array as a list of items?

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work". Does it crash? (post crash logs if so) Does your list show up empty?

Comment: Please post your code where you create the `String[] result`.

Comment: yes. it does crash. going to update the question.

Comment: so it crash when you add the arrayadapter on the postexecute but not on the createView?

Comment: Does getActivity() return null?

Comment: @greenapps I'm sorry. I don't know how to check if it does. Any pointers please?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin is it okay to set the arrayadapter outside of the async task? I thought that wasn't a good idea, so i added the code in onPostExecute. I checked if i can set arrayadapter with adobe_products from inside onPostExecute, that was possible. I think the problem is that adobe_products and result don't hold the same type of values..

Comment: if (getActivity() ==null){diplay a toast} else {set list adapter}.  If you use the adobe array in onPostExecute does that function? And where is the log?

Comment: Sorry I now see that you already tried inside. So yes apparently the arrays differ. Please show some items of them. And with the log: some more lines aroud what you already posted. I expect to see some more about that exception. Of course it is ok to do it in onpostexecute.

Comment: `String[] menuarray = new String[100];` You create 100 nulls, so when you pass that to your list, unless you put exactly 100 Strings in that array, you'll get an NPE. Use an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using an `ArrayList` instead of an `Array` (specially to populate List adapters, there's a reason they both end in "List" and not array), because they can grow after being declared.

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725825/arraylist-into-arrayadapter).